# React native listview add item not working

Tags: ios, listview, uicollectionview, react-native

I am new to react native and I was implemented a simple idea in my head. Basically, I am doing a 'todo list' like component which theres a add button below and items can be added. The problem arises after clicking on the add button and the list gets updated and the following xcode warning message appears. And I have realised, after implementing the ListView, that the app in the simulator slows down so much i couldn't even inspect. The alert popup would freeze the UI after some text are entered too, and the entire app needs to be built again since I couldn't do anything. Thanks for all the help!

**Main component: SurveyQn**

> 'use strict'
>
> import React, {
>       Component,
>       StyleSheet,
>       Text,
>       TouchableHighlight,
>       TextInput,
>       View,
>       ListView,
>       AlertIOS
>   } from 'react-native';
>
> var LongButton = require('./LongButton.js');
>
> class SurveyQn extends Component {
>
> ```
> constructor(props) {
>     super(props);
>
>     this.state = {
>         options: [{option: 'Pizza'}],
>     };
> }
>
> componentWillMount() {
>     this.dataSource = new ListView.DataSource({
>         rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2
>     })
> }
>
> _renderItem(item) {
>     return (
>         <LongButton 
>             text={item.option} 
>             onPress={() => {}} 
>             //btnViewStyle={styles.buttonView}
>             //btnTextStyle={styles.buttonText}
>         />
>     );
> }
>
> _addItem() {
>     AlertIOS.alert(
>         'Add new option',
>         null,
>         [
>             {
>                 text: 'Add',
>                 onPress: (text) => {
>                     var options = this.state.options;
>                     options.push({option: text})
>                     this.setState({ options: options})
>                 }
>             },
>         ],
>         'plain-text'
>     );
> }
>
> render(){
>     var dataSource = this.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.state.options);
>     return (
>         <View style={styles.container}>
>             <TextInput
>                 style={styles.question}
>                 placeholder="Question title"
>                 placeholderTextColor="#4B667B"
>                 selectionColor="#4B667B"
>                 onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}/>
>
>             <View style={styles.listView}>
>                 <ListView
>                     dataSource={dataSource}
>                     renderRow={this._renderItem.bind(this)}/>
>
>             </View>
>                 <TouchableHighlight 
>                     onPress={this._addItem.bind(this)}
>                     style={styles.buttonView}
>                     underlayColor='rgba(0,0,0,0)'>
>                     <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
>                         Add option
>                     </Text>
>                 </TouchableHighlight>
>         </View>
>
>
>     );
> }
> ```
>
> }
>
> var styles = StyleSheet.create({
>       container: {
>           width: 300,
>           flex :1,
>       },
>       listView: {
>           flex: 1,
>       },
>       question: {
>           height: 30,
>           fontSize: 20,
>           fontWeight: "100",
>           color: '#4B667B',
>           marginTop: 10,
>           marginBottom: 10,
>       },
>       buttonView: {
>           width: 300,
>           paddingVertical: 9,
>           borderWidth: 1,
>           borderColor: '#F868AF',
>           marginBottom: 13,
>       },
>       buttonText: {
>           textAlign: 'center',
>           fontSize: 25,
>           color: '#F868AF',
>           fontWeight: '500'
>       },
>   });

**ListView item: LongButton**

> 'use strict'
>
> import React, {
>       Component,
>       StyleSheet,
>       Text,
>       TouchableHighlight,
>       View,
>   } from 'react-native';
>
> class LongButton extends Component {
>
> ```
> render(){
>     return (
>         <TouchableHighlight 
>             onPress={this.props.onPress}
>             style={this.props.btnViewStyle}
>             underlayColor='rgba(0,0,0,0)'>
>             <Text style={this.props.btnTextStyle}>
>                 {this.props.text}
>             </Text>
>         </TouchableHighlight>
>     );
> ```
>
> }
>   }
>
> module.exports = LongButton;

Xcode warning message upon adding item on alert

> app[27881:11151280] the behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
>   app[27881:11151280] the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.
>   app[27881:11151280] The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is <_UIAlertControllerCollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7ff0685b1770>, and it is attached to ; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {0, 0}> collection view layout: <_UIAlertControllerCollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7ff0685b1770>.
>   2016-04-06 07:50:01.545 decisionapp[27881:11151280] Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.

**Updates:**
I tried this but its not working either. Could it be the alert causing these problems? Its just taking forever to render the alert after clicking on the btn.

> class SurveyQn extends Component {
>
> constructor(props) {
>          super(props);
>
> ```
>    this.state = {
>        options: [{option: 'Pizza'}],
>        dataSource : new ListView.DataSource({
>            rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2
>        })
>    };
> ```
>
> }
>
> componentWillMount() {
>          var data = this.state.options;
>          this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(data);
>      }
>
> _renderItem(item) {
>          return (
>              {item.option}
>          );
>      }
>
> _addItem() {
>          AlertIOS.alert(
>              'Add new option',
>              null,
>              [
>                  {
>                      text: 'Add',
>                      onPress: (text) => {
>                          var options = this.state.options;
>                          options.push({option: text})
>                          this.setState({ options: options})
>                      }
>                  },
>              ],
>              'plain-text'
>          );
>      }
>
> render(){
>          return (
>
> ```
>            <View style={styles.listView}>
>                <ListView
>                    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
>                    renderRow={this._renderItem.bind(this)}/>
>
>            </View>
>                <TouchableHighlight 
>                    onPress={this._addItem.bind(this)}
>                    style={styles.buttonView}
>                    underlayColor='rgba(0,0,0,0)'>
>                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
>                        Add option
>                    </Text>
>                </TouchableHighlight>
>        </View>
>
>
>    );
> ```
>
> }
>   }

Answer (score 1):

Before diving into complex EcmaScript notation, you can use simple notation. Here is a simple example of ListView. Please go through it and understand how it works.

```
var API = require('./API');
module.exports = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      rawData: [],
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2
      }),
      loaded: false,
    }
  },
  componentWillMount: function(){
    this.loadData();
  },
  loadData: function(){
    API.getItems()
    .then((data) => {
      this.setState({
        rawData: this.state.rawData.concat(data),
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(data),
        loaded: true,
      });
    });
  },
  render: function(){
    return(
        <ListView 
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={this.renderItem}
          style={styles.listView}>
        </ListView> 
    );
  },
  renderItem: function(item){
    return (
      <View>
          <Text>Custom Item</Text>
      </View>
    );
  },
}
```

In API.js, I am fetching data from an API.

```
getItems: function(){
        var REQUEST_URL = 'http://api.example.org/item/get?api_key=xxxx;
        return fetch(REQUEST_URL)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseData) => {
                return responseData.results.sort(sortByDate);
            });
    }
```

The code may not work, since I have not tested. But you can refer my sample project on github. [Repo](https://github.com/mihir-harbinger/explore-movies)

Comment: I have already went through ListViews tutorials but do you have any idea where i have gone wrong instead?

Comment: @jomaint yes. There are multiple mistakes in your code. `this.dataSource` used in `componentWillMount()` is wrong. There is nothing in your react class called as `dataSource`. You need to declare `datasource` in `getInitialState()` or constructor. After that you may solve the remaining potential errors.